# Rotating two vector randomly keeping the relative orientation between them unchanged

Tags: vector, rotation

Let's consider we have two vectors $A(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2, z_2)$. 
Now want to rotate these two vectors in $3D$ space (such that the relative orientation between them is always same).

How can I do that?

PS. I have tried to rotate the two vectors independently by angles $\phi$, $\theta$, and $\psi$. But I did not get the uniform spherical distribution. But I was getting a higher intensity near the pole of the sphere.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish, exactly? An uniformly distributed random 3D rotation transform, which you would apply to both vectors? If that's the case, you can get such a random rotation matrix in three dimensions with `RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]`, and rotate the vectors just by performing a matrix-vector multiplication (`r . v`, between a rotation matrix `r` and a vector `v`).

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{
  axis = RandomPoint[Sphere[]],
  angle = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}]
  },
 RotationMatrix[angle, axis]
 ]
```

should give you a rotation uniformly distributed over $\operatorname{SO}(3)$.

Answer (score 3):

My comment in a little more presentable form...

```
With[{vs = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2/3, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3}}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       NestWhile[
        RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]] &,
        {{0}}, Det[#] <= 0 &]}, 
     Graphics3D[{Gray, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, r.#}]] & /@ vs, Blue, 
       Opacity[1/10], Ball[{0, 0, 0}]}]], 4]] // Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

This also works in other dimensions (although 2D is the only one I'm going to show as an example here!):

```
With[{vs = {{1, 0}, {0, 2/3}}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       NestWhile[
        RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[2]] &,
        {{0}}, Det[#] <= 0 &]}, 
     Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, r.#}] & /@ vs, Blue, Opacity[1/10], 
       Ball[{0, 0}]}]], 4]] // Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Why the `NestWhile ... Det` construct? @MichaelSeifert explains this in the comment, and this construct selects a random affine matrix which doesn't perform a reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the nice representation. One more thing if I want to save this two vector as two new parameters (v1,v2). How can I do that? Could you please suggest.

Comment: @Bikash A minor variation: `With[{v1 = {1, 0, 0}, v2 = {0, 2/3, 0}}, Table[With[{r = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]}, Graphics3D[{Gray, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, r.#}]] & /@ {v1, v2}, Blue, Opacity[1/10], Ball[{0, 0, 0}]}]], 4]] // Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: [From the documentation:](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircularRealMatrixDistribution.html)  "`CircularRealMatrixDistribution` represents a uniform distribution over the orthogonal square matrices of dimension $n$, also known as the Haar measure on the orthogonal group $O(n)$."  The group $O(n)$ includes reflections as well as rotations;  you'd see this effect in 3D as well if you had more than two vectors.  To get "pure" rotations only (the group $SO(n)$, discard all matrices with $\det(M) = -1$ (or equivalently, select all matrices with $\det(M) = +1$.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I must say I missed that. Probably because documentation and examples tend to make the reflection part quite well hidden. I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess my primary blame goes to https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/random-matrices/random-rotations.html - reflections are not mentioned there although rotations are. Although it's reasonably obvious that reflections are included when reading the documentation a second time, it's not that clear on the first try...